# Get dimensions (width and height) of an Image hosted online

Tags: c#, vb.net, image, win-universal-app, dimensions

I want to get the dimensions of an Image, that is online, to know how tall the grid in which I would like to put it should be.
I tried to put it in a temporary grid to get the "ActualHeight" of the "Image" (UI Element), but it's "NaN" (or 0).

I usually use something like this (for Win32 .NET software), but I can't make it work in UWP:

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(URL), HttpWebRequest)
request.Method = "GET"
request.Accept = "image/*"
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim s As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(s)
Dim w As Integer = bmp.Width
Dim h As Integer = bmp.Height
```

Either VB.Net or C# would work.

Comment: I suppose it could give NaN if it hasn't finished downloading.

Comment: mmm.. you're right. 
How can I wait for it to finish, and then check the ActualHeight?

Comment: "Can't make it work" is not a good explanation of problem. Note that there are plenty of posts/articles explaining how to use async methods to obtain file from HTTP... You may want to search/read those first.

Comment: There's a short article explaining [Asynchronous programming in UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-universal-windows-platform-apps) which may lead to articles with examples.

Comment: Create a [`BitmapImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br243235) from the URI. In a handler for the [`ImageOpened`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.imageopened) event, get its size from the `PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight` properties.